# Apache - Using a subdirectory in a URL to load the root of the site

Tags: apache-2.4

Apologies if I missed it in a search but I'm bad at search terms and didn't find anything that is exactly what I need.

Our servers run Apache and for a stack I'm setting up, they want the following URL pattern

www.[sitename]/[subdirectory]

Where [sitename] is common to a number of stacks and [subdirectory] is unique to each stack.

For the other stacks that were set up, the Apache filesystem roots were set up to be

/files/[stackname]/[subdirectory]

Where the root of Apache was set to [stackname] so Apache would require the subdirectory to be in the requested URL to actually pull the site.

I made a case that there's got to be a better way for subsites to function rather than creating subdirectories on the file system; my main issue is that a lot of the scripts and Jenkins we used don't work with the additional filesystem-level subdirectory and we keep having to hardcode more and more exceptions and I'm not about that.

So in summary: in Apache, what options should I look at to force www.[sitename]/[subdirectory] to load my specific site?

Please comment if you need clarification, it's very early morning but this has been keeping me up all night; I feel like there's an easy way to do it, but I might be overthinking the problem and incorrectly searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in wholly in httpd, then use [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). If you have dynamic requirements, look at using .htaccess in your document root to add and remove URI paths to your URLs.

If you want more control, there should be a way of managing URLs in your programming language of choice.